# Using Akka Http and Circe for decoding JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala, akka-http, circe

I am trying to create Akka Http REST post endpoint mapping the JSON objects to the case class defined

```
import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.generic.auto._

case class JobEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, name: String, description: String, json_data :java.sql.blob)
```

The JSON is of type

```
{
 "id": "124",
 "name": "MYJOB",
 "description": "Test Job"
}
```

Now I want to map whole JSON to the 'json_data' as blob defined in the case class

```
  post {
  entity(as[JobEntity]) { jobEntity: JobEntity =>
    complete(createJob(jobEntity).map(_.asJson))
  }
}
```

I understand .map(_.asJson) would map the json to the JobEntity, Correct me if Its not like this
How do I map the whole JSON to the json_data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import Circe support methods. See the [example](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/blob/master/akka-http-circe/src/test/scala/de/heikoseeberger/akkahttpcirce/ExampleApp.scala) . And you need to add dependency `de.heikoseeberger % akka-http-circe`.